# Objetos em javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, objetos

Quando trabalhamos com objetos em javascript, e com o framework AngularJS, onde devemos escrever o código dos objetos?

Por exemplo, vou criar um objeto com algo parecido com isso:

```
var LogMessage = function(system, type, message, value, now) {
    this.system = system;
    this.type = type;
    this.message = message;
    this.value = value;
    this.time = now;
};
```

Caso eu precise usar ele em diversos services ou controllers, eu teria que copiar o código para todos os lugares, então eu deveria criar um arquivo js que tenha todos os meus objetos ?

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é criá-lo em um arquivo JS que é carregado antes de todos os outros, e sempre carregado também. Assim você pode utilizá-lo sempre.
Ex:

http://jsfiddle.net/BRWPM/1836/

Comment: Julyano, esta resposta é mais um comentário que uma resposta. Se não tens um exemplo concreto de como usar esses objetos dentro do Angular sugiro deixar só como comentário. Se quiseres [edit] e melhorar, excelente :)